# Unable to activate Python Virtual Env on compute in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have two computers, both running VS Code.

I was able to get the virtual environment running on one computer without problem running

```
python -m venv virtual_env
virtual_env\Scripts\activate
```

This machine only has Python3 installed and I ran that in a Python terminal in VS code.

On the second machine, it has both Python 3 and Python2 installed.  I have tried to set everything up identically between them, but when I run the same code, it fails.

When I run

```
python -m venv virtual_env
```

it returns either "No module named venv" (and it's running that in Python 2.7 despite the interpreter being set to 3.8)

When I run

```
python3 -m venv virtual_env
```

it says "The system cannot find the file specified".

The directory does appear in the explorer of Machine #2, but in the "Scripts" directory, there does not exist an "activate" file (like there is in Machine #1).

Not sure how to continue troubleshooting this.

Comment: Try call python using full path of the executable.

Comment: Do you mean the python.exe file that is in the "Scripts" directory that is created?  

I tried that and it output:
Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

And nothing else.

Comment: no, use the full python path when you create the virtual environment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I know what you mean.  

Full python path to where Python is installed on my computer, or the full path to where the VE is being set up?

Comment: Full python path to where Python is installed on your computer. For example "c:\Programs\Python37\python37.exe -m venv virtual_env"

Comment: That did not work, it still says invalid syntax. 
There are three executables in the filepath:
C:\Python38

python.exe, python3.exe, and python3.8.exe

I've tried your command in the terminal, but it hasn't worked.

I tried
C:\\Programs\\Python38\\python3.exe -m venv virtual_env and 
C:\Programs\Python38\python3.exe -m venv virtual_env
for all three of the Python executables and it said the same thing: The term 'C:\Programs\Python38\python3.8.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.'

But the files are there.

Comment: I just removed Python 2.7 and it worked.  Not sure why that was the conflict, but it seemed to resolve the issue.